# Is there an English translation of the Inuit story "Mother of the Dog Children"?

Tags: translation, inuit

I'm trying to find the translation to the Inuit story "Mother of the Dog Children", viewable here -- http://www.inuitmyths.com/dogmother.htm

Any resources that may help translate this text are helpful! Or even if there's another source with this text at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text on that page seems to come from [this collection](https://nbes.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/kappianaqtut__inuktitut_.pdf) of stories. The text is attributed to a Neil Christopher. The year at the end of the text  (ᕘᐊᔅ, **1901**, ᒪᑉᐱᒐᑦ 163-165) also appears in the References page at the end of the collection. I believe the reference is to the [collected notes](http://digitallibrary.amnh.org/handle/2246/1251) on Inuits by George Comer, James S. Mutch, and E.J. Peck. On pages 165 and 327 (pages 167 and 329 of the PDF) there are two versions of the story.

Comment: Oh my god, you are amazing. Thank you!!

Comment: @JoriRichman I found a version of that story in this book: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/48822454-mitos-y-leyendas-inuit which seems to be a Spanish translation of https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10831949-eskimo-folk-tales It matches the one in page 327 of the reference posted here